# HTTP GET call using HTTP Request Plugin in JENKINS Pipeline fails with NoHttpResponseException

Tags: spring-boot, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, httprequest, jenkins-plugins

I'm working on creating a ***JENKINS Pipeline*** that ***PULLS a Docker Image of Spring Boot application*** from the Registry and then deploys it on the ***Docker Demon*** running locally on my Windows 10 laptop.

The Spring Boot application exposes Health Check API  that produces a ***JSON*** response as ' {"status": "UP"} '. From with in my  Pipeline code, I'm invoking the ***GET*** Call using ***HTTP Request Plugin*** available on JENKINS that is installed on the JENKINS server running locally.
This call fails with ***NoHttpResponseException***. Below is some info of the setup.

HealthCheck URL : http://localhost:8088/actuator/health

JENKINS Server URL :  http://localhost:8080.

The ***Groovy*** Pipeline script successfully deploys the Docker Images locally. I was able to test the Health Check call using POSTMAN application which returned the desired result. However, the code to call Health Check URL from with Pipeline that follows the deployment of image causes failure.

I looked up online regarding ***NoHttpResponseException***, looks like it is happens when HTTP call is sent using a Stale connection. But not sure how to perform any task related to opening and Closing connections in the Pipeline script and if there is any support do it on the HTTP Request JENKINS Plugin.

Any help is much appreciated.

Below is my Pipeline code snippet that makes the HTTP GET call.

```
stage("Health Check"){

 def responseGetAll = httpRequest consoleLogResponseBody: true,
 contentType: 'APPLICATION_JSON',
 httpMode: 'GET',
 url: "http://localhost:8088/actuator/health",
 validResponseCodes: '200')

}
```

The Expected results should be the URL being invoked and returning a HTTP Response Code of 200 and Response content as 
{
    "status": "UP"
}

However, there is an exception on HTTP GET call as below :-

```
[Pipeline] httpRequest
HttpMethod: GET
URL: http://localhost:8088/actuator/health
Sending request to url: http://localhost:8088/actuator/health
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: localhost:8088 failed to respond
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:141)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259)
    at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:163)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:165)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:272)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at jenkins.plugins.http_request.util.HttpClientUtil.execute(HttpClientUtil.java:132)
    at jenkins.plugins.http_request.HttpRequestExecution.executeRequest(HttpRequestExecution.java:331)
    at jenkins.plugins.http_request.HttpRequestExecution.authAndRequest(HttpRequestExecution.java:278)
    at jenkins.plugins.http_request.HttpRequestExecution.call(HttpRequestExecution.java:215)
Caused: java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at jenkins.plugins.http_request.HttpRequestExecution.call(HttpRequestExecution.java:218)
    at jenkins.plugins.http_request.HttpRequestExecution.call(HttpRequestExecution.java:75)
    at hudson.remoting.LocalChannel.call(LocalChannel.java:45)
    at jenkins.plugins.http_request.HttpRequestStep$Execution.run(HttpRequestStep.java:336)
    at jenkins.plugins.http_request.HttpRequestStep$Execution.run(HttpRequestStep.java:318)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1$1.call(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at hudson.security.ACL.impersonate(ACL.java:290)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1.run(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:44)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Was the user changed in one of the `Dockerfile`s of your Docker image? (command `USER 5`). I assume that the user has to be root (id 0).

Answer (score 0):

You have to have the port mapped from the container running the SpringBoot app to the localhost & that host has to be the same one your running the http request on.

For example:

```
docker.image('your-image:version').withRun('--publish 8088:8088 ') {
  // wait for the container to spin up your app
  // run your test(s)
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Rich Duncan, for your response. I have exposed the docker Image successfully, only I'm exposing it via Docker command as below `docker run -d -p 8088:8088 --name=inventory-service inventory-service-docker:1.2` and not via Docker Plugin which is what you proposed. Also as mentioned on my post, I'm able to successfully test the app via POSTMAN. The problem seems to be the HTTP GET call using HTTP Request plugin is not getting invoked and not how the Docker image is being exposed.

Comment: So I can get a better understanding of the configuration issues - is the docker run happening in the same pipeline? Other things to keep in mind #1 you need to keep the container running until the health check finishes.  #2 You need to make sure the app is up and running before you run the health check

Comment: Yes, the Docker run is from the same Pipeline.But looks like I'm down the wrong path. I say so because, I removed  the code for HTTP Request Plugin and used URL invocation instead (though not recommended as per JENKINS docs) as `new URL("http://localhost:8088/actuator/health").openConnection(); `, even this code came back with an error. Looks like for some reason, my local installation of JENKINS is not able to communicate with Docker running locally. Though this is only a test locally for a POC, In PROD, Docker and JENKINS would be running on separate hosts on Linux where CURL would work fine